# Disable creation of specific file names on a windows share

Tags: windows, network-share, file-sharing

In Linux, it's easy to disallow the creation of files with specific names through the use of samba's veto files options. This is useful in situations where, for example, you have Macs connecting to the share and you don't want .DS_Store files everywhere. You just set up a veto file option and the server refuses to allow the creation of anything matching the regex.

I currently have a windows server that is providing file shares to the entire company. This file server must be backup up, of course. Due to the way the backup program works, it errors out after 100 files are not copied over to the backup server. These files it errors out on are part of the veto files list on the backup server.

While I'd like to just remove all these files from the windows server, they are auto generated by windows (Thumbs.db) and Mac (.TemporaryItems, .DS_Store, etc) and will be back by the time the backup runs again.

Is there any way to prevent the creation of specific file names in windows like there is in Linux? Google has not been particularly enlightening this time around, which makes me wonder if this is even possible.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Most backup software has a mechanism for excluding files or directories from the backup process. Rather than trying to prevent the `thumbs.db` and `.TemporaryItems` files from being created, maybe you can configure the backup software to skip them.

Comment: I did actually add in exclusions on the backup, but it has some errors with subfolders in .TemporaryItems folders created by mac. I'm sure I can figure something out for it eventually. I'm looking into changing backup software soon, so maybe I'll make file exclusions a higher priority on the new software.